# Updating repositories returns an error

Tags: networking, server, proxy, iptables, firewall

While installing DansGuardian, as per the instructions in the following link:[Dansguardian Content Filtering With Transparent Proxy On Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic](https://www.howtoforge.com/dansguardian-content-filtering-with-transparent-proxy-on-ubuntu-9.10-karmic), I set the iptables using `sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner proxy --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080` so that outgoing web requests that are made by anyone other than the proxy should be redirected to the proxy. I saved this into `/etc/init.d/tproxy`, so as to make these changes permanent.

After doing this, I deleted DansGuardian, squid and iptables to redo the entire procedure, using `sudo apt autoremove dansguardian squid iptables`

Everytime I run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install ..` now, I get the following error.

```
    dell@dell-Inspiron-5558:/etc$ sudo apt-get update
    Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu zesty InRelease
    Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
    Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
    Err:3 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
    Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
    Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
    Err:5 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
    Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    Err:6 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
    Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    Err:7 http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
    Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The mentioned resources, or repositories like ubuntu archives are inaccessible through the browser too. I suspect that this is due to the ip settings that had been saved before deleting the three mentioned files.

Is there a way of undoing the change `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner proxy --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080` despite the fact that I don't have iptables anymore?

Any suggestions to do the same, or any alternative diagnosis are welcome.

Comment: For whatever reason, you've changed standard Zesty - 17.04 repositories to 'old-releases'. Zesty is not old, it is still supported. Why did you do that?

Comment: Possibly it happened automatically with something else I did. I did not manually change it. Since I'm a complete newbie, could you tell me how to change it back?

Comment: Here you go: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories. Be careful next time.